# installing LuaJIT on redhat ppc64

Tags: lua, redhat, luajit, powerpc

I would like to install LuaJIT on my redhat system...in order to get OSRM working. I have tried to do so by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Building-OSRM)

and in particular i was following this part:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://luajit.org/download/LuaJIT-2.0.2.tar.gz
tar -zxvf LuaJIT-2.0.2.tar.gz
cd LuaJIT-2.0.2
make install PREFIX=/opt/osrm_infrastructure/LuaJIT-2.0.2
```

however i get the following error:

```
==== Building LuaJIT 2.0.2 ====
make -C src
lj_arch.h:324:2: error: #error "No support for PowerPC 64 bit mode"
 #error "No support for PowerPC 64 bit mode"
 ^
```

I am on a redhat 7 ppc64 architecture...

Is there a work around that might be available?

Comment: The error message seems clear to me; LuaJIT doesn't support PPC x64 yet.

Comment: But my question is about if there are any work arounds?

Answer (score 1):

Try using **LuaJIT 2.1** from [this fork](https://github.com/PPC64/LuaJIT), which has support for PowerPC 64-bit Little Endian (ppc64le). It it was not tested with OSRM, but it works with some Lua software.